# C++ Hardware Development

Tags: c++, embedded, hardware, debian, ports

I was wondering if there are any sets of C++ classes in order to interact with hardware devices, I mean, I/O trough ports like Serial or Parallel or something like that.

I've found some info but only in C, I hope there are C++ classes already written.

Comment: Why so eager to use cpp instead of c ? They are different and yet they're similar, if you know one, chances are you know the other on decent level.

Comment: [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) has support for serial ports.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: If at all, that implication works only from C++ to C - the other way around is much harder.

Comment: @JuanCB: if the C code is for kernel drivers, then there is no C++ code.

Comment: Are you talking about C++ classes that interact with hardware through an operating system like Windows or Linux, or are you talking about "bare metal" access like often happens in deeply embedded systems?  There is a **world** of difference there... (there is also a middle ground - for example a real time operating system, but from the devices listed in your question, it seems like you're talking about something like a desktop system)

Comment: @stefaanv:  You think you cannot write kernel level drivers in C++!?  Why not?  C++ has all the system level capabilities of C.  It is true perhaps in Linux that C++ is discouraged, primarily I suspect  through some irrational dislike of it from Linus Torvalds, but no one mentioned Linux in this case.

Comment: @clifford: good point, I thought of linux because of the debian-tag, but indeed, C++ is possible if the kernel allows it to be linked in (which I thought was the problem in Linux)

Comment: @stefaanv: Equally good point - I do not notice the Debian tag. If Linux or specifically Debian were relevant it should have been mentioned in the question, not just a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded hardware is typically proprietary, so any such library would still require some sort of hardware abstraction layer (this is true of both C and C++).  UART and GPIO are relatively trivial but at the same time very chip specific, and often there are application specific requirements too, so the utility of such a library is questionable.

It might be useful to define some common abstract interface to these resources so that application layer code would be portable between platforms, but any generic interface available may or may not suit your requirements.  So you will often be better off implementing your own design and reusing it rather than being constrained by anybody else's implementation.

If you can find suitable C libraries, then the simplest approach would be to implement suitable C++ wrappers.  C code is entirely interoperable with C++.

If the standard C library for your platform has been ported to support stdio on devices such as UARTs then the standard C++ iostream library will work, but does not provide a standard low-level interface for setting framing and baud rate; you could implement that directly or through custom ioctl() commands.  If stream I/O semantics are suitable, you can implement low-level drivers for other devices and file-systems to allow access via iostream.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your target platform. http://www.arduino.cc/ wraps all the I/O in C++.